# How to customize multiselect edit mode for uitableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Is it possible to customize the multiselect edit mode? So instead of the default selection icon (the circle with the checkmark), I need to show a custom one, with selected and unselected states.

I also need to indent the cell more to the right.

Obviously I would like to use as much as possible of the system provided animations.

HEre's a screenshot of the sample editing mode of uitableview. (My cell is much more complicated :)

Thanks,
Jason[image]

Comment: Why don't you customise the cell and add button with background image for your checkmark

Comment: So when the cell goes into editing mode with multiselection enabled the content animates indented to the right and buttons appear. This is by default. So doing this myself would require writing the animation code to animate and add the button. I would like to use the framework provided animations as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can customise the cell.. create a `UITableViewCell` with a UIButton and set the custom images you want for the selected and default states and load this custom cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`