# TableView editing mode: remove default selected background color

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift4

I am working with a tableview in editing mode. I am using the checkmark multi select method as you can see in the iOS built in mail edit mode -- also linked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22011353/how-to-customize-multiselect-edit-mode-for-uitableview).

My issue is that when a cell is selected, the background changes to the default tintColor.

My expected outcome is that the tableViewCell onSelect fills in the checkmark but does not change the background color.

I have tried changing the selectionStyle to .none -- this makes it so I cannot select the cell at all in editing mode. I have also tried changing the selected background view without success.

```
open override func viewWillLoad(withData data: Any!) {
    self.view.backgroundColor = .gray
    self.tableView = UITableView()
    self.tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
    self.tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = true

    self.view.addSubview(tableView)
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.init(rawValue: 3)!
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // dequeueing my cell here

    cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]
    // cell.selectionStyle = ????

    return cell
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this other than creating a custom button?

Comment: have you looked at setting cell.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor??

Comment: @dniswhite Yes, I tried this.

Comment: create your own UITableViewCell?

Comment: @dniswhite I am using a custom cell. I moved my code into the delegate function for simplicity sake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that there is a specific background for tableViews that use Multiple Selection!

My solution was to use the following code on my cells:

```
let selectedView = UIView()
selectedView.backgroundColor = cellBackgroundColor
self.multipleSelectionBackgroundView = selectedView
self.selectionStyle = .default
```

If you are only using single selection you can use the following:

```
let selectedView = UIView()
selectedView.backgroundColor = cellBackgroundColor
self.selectedBackgroundView = selectedView
self.selectionStyle = .default
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
   shouldHighlightRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
     return !tableView.isEditing
}
```

Comment: I am not worried about the background color of the cell, only worried about the selected state highlight/background. All of my cells will be in editing mode, which triggers this call on all cells on init. Unfortunately it does not work :(

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just posted what I found as the solution to my problem

Comment: *"Try this:"* is not a good description for an answer. It's much better to explain what was wrong and explain how the answers solves the issue.

Comment: It was just update for my previous answer, so I think this description is OK in this case. Maybe I should not have deleted the previous answer to mislead you.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove that highlighted color in storyboard.
[image]

select selection to None

And also you can remove that color by code

```
cell.selectionStyle = .none
```

Comment: Setting the selectionStyle to none using this style of editing disables the checkmarks completely on select.

Comment: You wanna select multiple cell with same color?